# How to convince friends using Windows and Mac to switch to Ubuntu

Tags: windows, mac

How can I convince my sceptical friends using Windows and Mac to switch to Ubuntu?

Comment: Questions like this are more for discussions and belong on either a mailing list of http://ubuntuforums.org

Comment: Well it certainly is noble that you want to promote Ubuntu to your friends, we would prefer that this type of discussion happened elsewhere due to its argumentative and subjective nature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linux doesn't degrade with the time even if you install / uninstall a lot of software as Windows does

You can move the installed OS from machine to machine with little or none issues even with different chipsets/motherboards

When update your OS, you also update your apps.

You can use your hardware longer due to less system requirements

You can customize the system better

You can choose from different Desktop environments (Windows an Mac user don't know even what this means)

You can trust software more than "cool programs" downloaded from "a cool site"

You get features others try to achieve with 3rd party software with different success (compiz, multilevel clipboard, virtual desktops)

You easily can run services on your workstation to act as a server an vice versa

If you don't like a particular Linux Distro, you can pick another one

You can develop your own distro (from scratch or based on someone's else)

Answer (score 2):

Tell them,

- Ubuntu is free and legal.
- That they don't have to worry at all about viruses,Spyware,Adware,Keyloggers, etc
- It's very secure than windows.
- The feautures of ubuntu and support.

**Look @ the following links**,

- **[How to convert Windows Users to Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=58862)**

Comment: Some of this information is incorrect, incomplete and very one-sided. Arguments as incomplete as these hinder more than they help.