# How can I convert people to Ubuntu from Windows?

Tags: convert

Prior to using Ubuntu (even knowing about it) I was using Windows like everybody else. I tried Ubuntu at a friends house and I liked it (that was a long time ago) but now I've installed and I'm using about it for About a month and learning commands and getting to know extensive resources like AskUbuntu.

it's such a great OS and does everything a normal Joe would want to do with his computer, but problem is people don't know about it and those who know about it think that it's for developers and normal consumer can't handle Linux, which is a nothing but a stereotype IMHO.

so my question is, How can I convert Windows people to Ubuntu and make them believe that it's not just for hackers and developers?

Comment: We do not handle questions like this because they are opinion based  but anyways take a look at [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/18174/665251)  and [this forum](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=58862)

Comment: Be sure you have a Live USB drive in your pocket when you visit people so you can show them Ubuntu.

Comment: thanks for response, linked answers helped me, I've successfully convinced *One* guy to try Ubuntu alongside windows and horribly failed 6 times.